# JavaScript object to file object

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I'm working on adding images to page, do something with collection of added images (preview etc) and finally I want them save. Everything is cool until the `files` object is used to show or save the photo.

```
var input = document.getElementById('files');
var files = input.files;
```

as it is an array of objects read only - it is impossible to manipulate it freely. For working with that array friendly I maped it like that:

```
var addedFiles = added(files); 
function added(from) {
    return $.map(from, function (i) {
         var x = { lastModified: i.lastModified, lastModifiedDate: i.lastModifiedDate, name: i.name, size: i.size, type: i.type, webkitRelativePath: i.webkitRelativePath }
         return x;
    });
}
```

... then do something with those files - and I want to preview, and then save - but for example during preview I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

    function readImage(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var image = new Image();

            image.addEventListener("load", function () {
                preview.innerHTML += drawHtml(this, file);
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src); //blob version
            }); 
            image.src = reader.result; //file version
            image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file) //blob version
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); // here fire the error
    }
```

When I pass for testing originally `file` obj to above code every thing is working.

**Question:**
How to create custom obj (in my case array of obj) that can be parse to `file` obj

**P.S.** In project I'm using jquery and javascript

Comment: Why are you needing to manipulate `input.files`? You're converting the File objects (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to something else that isn't a file object anymore. Maybe there's a different approach you can take.

Comment: _Maybe_ you could implement the `Blob` interface. That's at least one thing that's missing in your objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: - before the client sends a picture to the server after adding it, he can add additional informations
- during the generation of the preview, I'm using ajax to connect to the database to check if the picture already exists in db - depending on the situation it shows the error that the img already exists

every thing before img is saved

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mapping the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects to new, incompatible objects, you could instead *wrap* them with the additional things you need, but then use the underlying original files when reading them:

```
const fileSelections = Array.prototype.map.call(input.files, file => ({
  // This will let you get to the underlying file in the wrapper objects
  file,

  // If you want pass-throughs, you can do stuff like this:
  get lastModified() { return file.lastModified },

  // And you can add your own properties/methods as you please
});

function readImage(fileSelection) {
  // Unwrap the file
  const file = fileSelection.file;

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const image = new Image();

    image.addEventListener("load", function () {
      preview.innerHTML += drawHtml(this, file);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src); //blob version
    }); 
    image.src = reader.result; //file version
    image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file) //blob version
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct answer is blob - it's something amazing for me.

```
//from is the array of obj - files
  function added(from) {
                    var out = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
                        (function (obj) {
                            var readerBase64 = new FileReader();
                            var obj = from[i];
                            readerBase64.addEventListener("load", function () {
                                var fileBase64 = readerBase64.result;
                                var row = { name: obj.name, size: obj.size, type: obj.type, base64: fileBase64 }
                                out.push(row);
                            });
                            readerBase64.readAsDataURL(obj); 
                        })(from[i]);
                    }
                    return out;
                }
```

'out' is a table of my own objects with base64, so I can create images for preview and 'do something functions' in the end I'm going to use base64 for create files.

[here link for question related to my next step - creating img from blob (where I'm using additional lib b64toBlob)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214645/code-is-working-while-debug-but-without-not-javascript)